# The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #temp_display () values () uses temp table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, ss

I have upgraded the SSIS package from 2008 to 2014.Also, I have changed the provider value to "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1 ". When I run I got error like

> OLE_SOURCE_RECORDS [9]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #temptest
>           ( [a],[b]) values (0,'b' in procedure SPtest' uses a temp table.".

I researched and found we need to use With result set instead of temp table.But I need to modify all the sql query in SP.

Is there is any way we can run package without changing Stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use local temporary table in SSIS you should be aware of two settings:

1) `RetainSameConnection` property to True

Local temporary table is visible only in current session. So you need to retain connection between components.

2) `ValidateExternalMetadata` to False

Comment: It doesnot work . I am getting the same error.I am getting the connection string dynamically from varaible.

Comment: @Overcrash007 Please post your SSIS package with description.

Comment: package will dynamically take the connection string from varriable.After upgrading ssis package from 2008 to 2014, I try to run package it calls stored procedure which uses #temporary table but got above shown error.  Whats the issue with temp table after upgrading and how can i solve it.

Comment: Found change temp table to table variable in stored procedure or execute stored procedure with result set.